# Unable to access https://localhost:3000 from inside docker container using docker-compose but can access via DNS name on a mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the docker-compose file below.

```yaml
version: "2.4"
services:
  test-database:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    build: ms-sql-db
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: removed
      MSSQL_PID: removed
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 31433:1433
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/opt/mssql
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z localhost 1433 || exit -1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 40s

  api:
    image: removed/api:1.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile-dev
    depends_on:
      test-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./Api:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5001:5001
    tty: true
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail --insecure https://localhost:5001/api/health
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s
  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: webapp/Dockerfile-dev
    depends_on:
      api:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail --insecure https://localhost:3000/
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s
```

the container fails to star due to the health check.

```yaml
      test: curl --fail --insecure https://localhost:3000/
```

However, if I use the dns name for the container created by docker-compose as shown below it works.

```yaml
      test: curl --fail --insecure https://ui:3000/
```

I'm using a Mac and Docker Desktop.

**Edit**
Adding specific issue for clarity. My issue is that in container I can only access `https://ui:3000/` and I can't access `https://localhost:3000/` and I'd rather not couple the health check to the service name.

Comment: What's the question? Can you not use `ui`?

Comment: @LeonAves edited to make issue more clear

Comment: What's the error you get when using localhost?